# Magento 1.4 cms pages not being hidden in menu, even if it's set to disabled

Tags: php, magento

I've encountered a strange thing in one magento installation, I haven't touched it in awhile so they must've added stuff to it.

The issue is: They set the cms page to 'disabled' so that page now yields a 404 error each time it's visited(which is good), but for some reason the links.phtml is still releasing *all* links, not checking if the page is disabled or not.

So I put this here to test:

```
<?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>

<?php if(count($_links)>0): ?>
<ul class="links"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>

<?php
$cmsCollections = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection();
$attribute = "title";  
$value = $_link['title'];  
$cmsCollections->addFieldToFilter($attribute, $value);
$item = $cmsCollections->getFirstItem();
$id = $item->getData('is_active');
if($id == 1){
    echo "CMS PAGE ". $value." ACTIVE";
}else{
   echo "CMS PAGE ". $value."  is INACTIVE";
}


?>
```

The odd part here is that I keep getting the wrong results ...

I'm no magento expert here so maybe anyone knows how to do this properly in getLinks ? I found no options to filter stuff there unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elijah, CMS BLOCk collection should be ...

```
    $cmsCollections=
Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1);
```

CMS Page Collection

```
    $CMSpageColl
=Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1);
```

If you want a particular CMS block then you can get it using idendifier

```
  $cmsCollections = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('identifier',indefiername);
```

If you want a particular CMS block then you can get it usign idendifier

```
$cmspageCollections =
Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('identifier',indefiername);
```